# PHPscript login form SQL doesn't go through even user ans password in the DB

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to write a simple login script with the DB. The connection to DB is ok. But I don't know why the script doesn't find a match in the DB and the redirect header is not sent.

HTML:

```
 <form method=POST action=$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]>
<p>mail</p>
<input type=text name=user>
<p>password</p>
 <input type=password name=pass>
 <br />
 <input type=submit value="login">
 </form>
```

PHP:

```
 if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {

echo $form;

 } else {

  require_once 'db_conn.php';
  if (!empty($_POST['user']) || !empty($_POST['pass'])) {



    $user_name = $_POST['user'];
    $password = $_POST['pass'];
    $pass_crypt = md5($password);
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `mail` = '."'$user_name'".'AND `password` =  '."'$pass_crypt'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

    if (!$result || mysqli_num_rows($result) < 1 ) {

        echo $form;
        die(mysqli_error($conn));
    } else {

        header('Location: index.html');

     }

   }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. The script runs fine. The problem was in the script of adding a user. I didn't use md5() encrytion there. I changed it and now it works fine.
Thanks to evreyone

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your query string. It is not written properly. Correct

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `mail` = '."'$user_name'".'AND `password` =  '."'$pass_crypt'";
```

to

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `mail` = '$user_name' AND `password` =  '$pass_crypt'";
```

Comment: @tavi_tudor..Are you getting values from `form`?

Comment: yes. I found that if I take out the md5 encryptyon the script goes well. But now I don't know how to encrypt it.

Comment: @tavi_tudor..I can't found any mistake with the encryption. It will work fine if you are getting values for `$user_name` and `$password`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<form method=POST action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" >
```

instead

```
<form method=POST action=$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]>
```

Comment: I didn't say but the form is a PHP variable which a echo $form

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax in your $form variable

```
$form = "<form method=POST action=\"".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."\">"." other part of form </form>";
```